# How to access model metadata from custom materialization

Tags: dbt

I am currently writing a custom `dbt` materialization and I would like to know what is the best way / pattern to access the "current" model metadata from the materialization itself.

### Background

My model consists of two files:

- `sample_model.yaml` (with the model metadata)

```
version: 2

models:
 - name: sample_model
    description: This is a test view to test a materialization
    config:
      schema: temp
      materialized: custom_view
    columns:
      - name: custom_view_column_a
        description: This is a test column A in a view
      - name: custom_view_column_b
        description: This is a test column B in a view
```

- `sample_model.sql` (with the "actual" model)

```
SELECT
  1 AS custom_view_column_a,
  2 AS custom_view_column_b
```

### My solution

In my custom materialization (`custom_view`) I would like, for example, to access the columns defined in the model metadata (`sample_model.yaml`). For the moment I could access them using the `graph` variable, in this way:

```
{% set models = [] %}
{% for node in graph.nodes.values() | selectattr("resource_type", "equalto", "model") | selectattr("name", "equalto", this.identifier) %}
    {% do models.append(node) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set model_metadata = models|first %}
{% set model_columns = model_metadata.get("columns") %}
```

### Possible improvements

This approach works quite well, however it "feels" a bit like (ab)using a sort of "global variable". Also the `graph` could become very large considering it stores both the metadata *and* the SQL of all the models in the project!

**Is there any other (local) object / variable I can access from the materialization that only stores the metadata of the model it's currently being materialized?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`{{ model }}`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/model) gives you the data from the graph for the current model node. I think it should work inside a materialization:

```sql
{% set model_metadata = model %}
```

You may want to gate it with `execute` -- I'm not really sure if the first parsing pass templates the materialization code:

```sql
{% set model_metadata = model if execute else {} %}
```